# Segment cell organelles with pixellib

Tags: python, single-cell, tensorflow

I've got some images of cell organelles and I really want to avoid labeling them by hand. The images all look something like the image below. Is there already an existing model specifially for cells? I tried it with existing models like `mask_rcnn_coco.h5` or `deeplabv3_xception65_ade20k.h5` but as they aren't built for cells the results aren't good.

My code is pretty basic right now:

```
from pixellib.instance import instance_segmentation

from PIL import Image

    def segmentImage():
        segment_image = instance_segmentation()
    
        segment_image.load_model("mask_rcnn_coco.h5")
        segment_image.segmentImage("cell.jpg", output_image_name="cell_seg.jpg", show_bboxes=True)
```

Cell example image:

[image: cell organelle example image]

Example segmentation result:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am the creator of PixelLib. PixelLib supports instance segmentation of 80 classes of objects using pre-trained coco model. Cell organelles is not part of the classes supported.
The only solution is to train your own custom model. PixelLib supports custom training of a model using your own labelled dataset. Read this [article](https://towardsdatascience.com/custom-instance-segmentation-training-with-7-lines-of-code-ff340851e99b) I published on how to train a custom model with PixelLib.

Comment: Wow, what an honor that you personally respond. Thank you very much. I actually already found this article and I wanted to avoid labelling the cells by hand. But I guess it pays off in the long run hopefully. I see a lot of potential in your work for Bioinformatics in general and especially for the project i'm working on now. If done right I'm sure PixelLib can help save us a lot of work :)

Comment: Thank you......